# Using Ajax return data to fill a span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, razor

I have this ajax call that is called when data is successfully update:

```
function success(data) {
var userId = $('#ID').val();
$.ajax({
    url: "/Orders/DraftOrderDetailsLineItems",
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    datatype: 'json',
    data: { "customerId": userId },
    success: function (data) {
        if (data != "") {
                $('#draftOrderItems').html(data);
                $('#lineItemTable').show();
                $('#draftOrderShipping').show();
                $('#totalDraftSalePrice').html(data.SubtotalBasePrice);

            //TODO: if this is the last item, hide the lineitems
        }
        console.log("Call line item partial" + data);

    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error("[Error in Ajax Request, Get Line Items] Code:" + jqXHR.status + " Error:" + errorThrown + " \nText Status:" + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

The problem I am having is I am trying to get the HTML for the totalDraftSalePrice to update with the new value after the update (in the data).  The data field is called SubTotalBasePrice.  I can see it in my json visualizer and search for it in the visualizer, I just can't seem to get the code to update the HTML tag.  What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the SPAN visible or have a display that allows it to appear?  Hidden elements don't get updated in jQuery, from my experience.

Comment: Do you see the expected data in `#draftOrderItems`?

Comment: Never ever use `async: false`. It is a terrible practice and has been deprecated. You should be seeing warnings in browser dev tools console not to use it

Comment: All the tags are showing as expected it is the totalDraftSalePrice tag that is not updating with the updated data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response data type fields is `dataType` not `datatype`
This means `data` is a string not an object therefore `data.SubtotalBasePrice` is undefined since strings have no member `SubtotalBasePrice`

So your request should be like

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to console the value of `"data.SubtotalBasePrice"`

if not try to `console.log(data.SubtotalBasePrice);` and
    if it is in array try `data[0].SubtotalBasePrice` ,may be this can 
    work 
    or `data['SubtotalBasePrice']`

Comment: I have tried this:

 success: function (data) {
            console.log("Adjusted Quantity in cart");
            $('#totalDraftSalePrice').html("$" + formatCurrency(data.SubTotalBasePrice));
            success(data);
        },

And in the console I get data as undefined

Comment: In the JSON visualizer is shows as:

[JSON]
    SubTotalBasePrice: "[Value]"

so when i try data.SubTotalBasePrice I still get an undefined